# X11: Removing event from queue

Tags: events, event-handling, x11

I'm creating an FPS demo using an Engine called: Gameplay. I'm currently trying to define a captureMouse() function into the engine so the player can look around the map. I've already been able to pin the cursor to the center of the window and turn it invisible, but as I move the mouse the screen (camera) seems to "vibrate" as it moves around. After a lot of tinkering with X11 functions I figured that the XWarpPointer() function I'm using to warp the cursor back to the center of the window is adding a "mouse moved" event to the event queue.

**X11 Question:** How can I identify and remove an event from the event queue before it is captured by the event cycle?

**Question:** Has anyone been a similar problem and solved in a different manner? If so, what did you do?

I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. I have no extensive knowledge of X11, but I really need to add this to the engine so I can, in turn, add it to my game.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using XtAppMainLoop to handle your events.

This is actually a call to XtAppNextEvent followed by XtDispatchEvent.

If you replace the XtAppMainLoop with a loop calling XtAppNextEvent to get the next event and check its type (the type field of the XEvent structure).

If you want to handle the event call XtDispatchEvent, do nothing to ignore it.

The loop needs to exit when XtAppGetExitFlag returns true (or add your own exit flag).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the functions you described are part of Xtoolkit. However, the game engine uses pure Xlib. Here's a link to the post with the code I wrote: http://www.gameplay3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=241&sid=fa488aa562f03ebd2f940b49d4128e58                          You'll have to go down to the 8th post. Thats where the code is at.

Comment: I didn't realise you were using a game library. Looking at the code, are you overriding Game::mouseEvent and returning true?

Comment: I do override the function in my project source code, but I don't explicitly return true. Why do you ask?

Comment: In Platform::mouseEventInternal the event is passed to the script controller if mouseEvent returns false and in several places, if mouseEventInternal returns false touchEventInternal is called.  I'm wondering if any of these are doing something with the event and causing your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although what you suggested wasn't the problem, it made me go back and revisit some older code in the mouseEvent() function. Apparently the problem wasn't with something missing in the x11 code. Instead, some of my old code was conflicting with the function that was capturing the mouse pointer. Now everything is ok :D